# How to ignore re-render after store changes?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have a few components where I outright want to ignore a re-render (or any other change to those components) if certain parts of the store change. How can this be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
   if ('not rerender condition') {
     return false;
   } else {
     return true
   }
}
```

Comment: `else {return true}`

Answer (score 0):

Add the shouldComponentUpdate function to that component and return false.

```
shouldComponentUpdate() {
   return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to ignore updates to a component, you should use the [shouldComponentUpdate](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate) lifecycle method. This should be implemented in your component class and always return false. Here's an example:

```
class CustomComponent extends React.Component {
  shouldComponentUpdate() {
    return false;
  }

  render() {
    /* ... */
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Other than `shouldComponentUpdate`, you could try to use the attribute `key` of component to stop re-render. If the preview `key` is the same as the next `key`, React would not re-render this component.

Comment: can you give some example on this?

Comment: `Keys should be stable, predictable, and unique. Unstable keys (like those produced by Math.random()) will cause many component instances and DOM nodes to be unnecessarily recreated, which can cause performance degradation and lost state in child components.` from [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reconciliation.html#tradeoffs). In some cases like multiple nested Components, it works!